# Can a random product state be expressed as a MPS (Matrix product state)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, tensor-network

$ |\psi\rangle = \prod_{i=1}^{N}|s_{i}\rangle $ where, $|s_{i}\rangle = \cos\left (\frac{\theta_{i}}{2}\right )|\uparrow_{i}\rangle + \exp{(i\phi_{i})}\sin\left (\frac{\theta_{i}}{2}\right )|\downarrow_{i}\rangle$. $\theta_{i}$ and $\phi_{i}$ are randomly chosen from the intervals $[0,\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi]$ respectively. Can this random product state be written as an matrix product state?

Comment: In fact it can with unit bond dimension...

Comment: Sure it can. Your amplitudes are the respective 1x1 matrices.

Comment: You have been posting questions about MPS already a year ago.  By now you should know enough about them to make your question more precise.  What are your thoughts, and where are you struggling?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $A_1^{\uparrow} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)\end{pmatrix}$, $A_1^{\downarrow} = \begin{pmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\sin\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/275822)

Comment: I disagree, but ok.